# Grouping two arrays into one array of common results

Tags: java, arrays, math, recursion

This is a logic problem I cant seem to wrap my head around.

What I wish to achieve is to match two different products from two different sets that have the same total value into packages.

for simplicity sake lets say we have two arrays with [id,price] pairs

```
array1 = [id=A,price=1],[id=B,price=2],[id=C,price=3]
array2 = [id=A,price=2],[id=B,price=1],[id=C,price=1]
```

the cheapest package I can make is for $2 by combining `array1 [id A]` and `array2 [id B]`
but I can also combine `array1 [id A]` and `array2 [id C]` to make a $2 package.

So what I am trying to get is a set of packages that could be grouped by total value. but only according to what the is selected in the first array.

eg : (purely for visualization purposes) :

```
  package1 :
  total : $2  
    1st option :
      [id=A,price=1]
    2nd option
      [id=B,price=1]
      [id=C,price=1]

  package2 :
  total : $3  
    1st option :
      [id=A,price=1]
    2nd option
      [id=A,price=2]

 package3 :
  total : $3  
    1st option :
      [id=B,price=2]
    2nd option
      [id=B,price=1]
      [id=C,price=1]
```

etc.
Im assuming I will need to recursively iterate through the results, I just keep going down the wrong path and maybe someone could point  me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to calculate result for all combinations, and store the options to a map structure at the time the results are calculated.

If you are using a custom object for your class (MyOption):

```
Map<Integer, Map<MyOption, List<MyOption>> result = new HashMap<>();
```

Or, if you're using object array:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Object[], List<Object[]>> result = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: I like this option. I see what you are saying. I will give that a try shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can generate a [price] <--> [item list] map, the `key` is price, the `value` is a list of item with same price. e.g.
    `[1] -- [Item A, Item B], [2] -- [Item D, Item E, Item Z]`, then you can generated different package base on the map.

```
private void methodToGenerateCombinationOfItems {
    Map<Integer, List<Item>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Item>>();
    updateArrayDataToMap(map, array1);
    updateArrayDataToMap(map, array2);
    ... ...
    // now the map should contains [price X] <--> [list of items with price X]
    // if you want to order by price, you may want to use TreeMap instead of HashMap.
}

private void updateArrayDataToMap(Map<Integer, List<Item>> map, List<Item> itemArr) {
    for( Item item : itemArr) {
        if( map.contains(item.getPrice()) ) {
            map.get(item.getPrice()).add(item);
        } else {
            List<Item> listTmp = new ArrayList<Item>();
            listTmp.add(item);
            map.put(item.getPrice(), listTmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great thanks, it gives me a great starting point. I appreciate the time you took to reply.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code for this:

```
List<Package> results = new ArrayList<>();
for(Item item:array1) {
    if (item.getPrice() < 2) {
        addAllPackagesStartingWith(item, results);
    }
}

// add all packages where an item from array 1 can be paired with an item in array 2
void addAllPackagesStartingWith(Item item, List<Package> results) {
    for (Item array2Item:array2) {
        if(item.getPrice() + array2Item.getPrice() < 2) {
            results.add(new Package(item, array2Item));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will be trying this shortly thank you for your fast response, I am unsure why it should check if the price is less than 2 though?

Comment: If the price in array1 is more than 2, then the package cannot add up to 2. If the price in array1 is equal to 2 then an item from array2 would have to be zero in price to come in at 2 dollars or under. I presumed you'd want a package of two items one from each...